# When and how is secret key exchanged in SMB2 for HMAC signing

Tags: smb

For SMB2 session establishment which supports HMAC-SHA256 for signing the packets, when is the secret key exchanged over the network? And how?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246492.aspx) for learn how to do so.

This is a link for the Microsoft spec of SMB2.

Answer (score 0):

During the authentication the sessionKey is established. Note that the private keys do not leave the machine. They're secret :)